# Cannot get node hello world app to deploy on GCloud

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I cannot for the life of me the the hello world app that google provides to work.  I am following the tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

I have followed all the steps and the hello world code runs perfectly on my local machine.  However, when I try to run
    gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote
I get the following output:

```
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - empirical-lens-111022/default (from [C:\Users\zakpt\Downloads\nodejs-getting-started-1-hello-world\nodejs-getting-started-1-hello-world\app.yaml])
 Deployed URL: [https://empirical-lens-111022.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Beginning deployment...
Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.

Provisioning remote build service.
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Couldn't connect to the Docker daemon.
```

I have no idea what to do, since the Docker isn't mentioned at all in the tutorial, and googling has only shown solutions for OSX. I am on Windows 10

Comment: Hey, which version of gcloud are you using? Run 'gcloud version' to see.

Comment: I ended up going gcloud config and installed every possibility listed, and it started working after that.  Not entirely sure why, but I'll take it I guess. I'm on 0.9.83